# How to update an object from an array of objects in mongodb and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I want to update an object from array of objects in the backend and db.

How do i do it . Here are the codes.

Userschema.

```
const userschema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true

},
place: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
products:[
    {
        brandname: {
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        productname:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        },
        quantity:{
            type:Number,
            required:true
        },
        price:{
            type:Number,
            required:true
        },
        description:{
            type:String,
            required:true
        }
        
    }
]
,
tokens:
    [{
        token: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
    ]
})

const User = mongoose.model('USER', userschema)
```

and here is the api code for backend.

```
router.put('/productupdate',async (req,res)=>{
const objid=req.query.id;                         //getting mongo Objectid from here.

const datas=req.body
const result=await User.updateOne(
    {'products._id':objid},
    {
    $set : {'products':datas}
    }
    )
    
    if(!result){
        res.status(403).send('unsuccessfull')
    }
    else{
        res.status(200).json(result)
        console.log("update data:",result)
    }
})
```

i want to update the product details based on the objectid in  the array of objects in product array.

with the above code its deleting every other objects in the product array.

I only want to update selected fields in the object not all of them. How can i do it. please  help. Stuck on this for almost 2 days now.

Comment: What does `datas` represent here? A new object to insert into the array?  You probably want to look into something like the `$push` operator or array filters depending on what specific change you are trying to make to the array.

Comment: Datas there represents the req body which contains the fieldname and value name i want to update in the object.

such as "price":400 or

"brandname" : "adidas",
"quantity":300